# Checking if string from database is utf-8 encoded in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8

For 2 days now, I've been searching for ways to check if a value from the database is utf-8 encoded or not in Java. So far, I've read that strings in Java are using unicode (utf-16) encoding. I've tried following the suggested answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890907/implement-a-function-to-check-if-a-string-byte-array-follows-utf-8-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866231/checking-if-a-string-is-utf-8-compatible-for-mysql) but neither seem to work properly. The first one always returns false while the second one would always return true.

An example of strings I try to check are as follows wherein everything except the last string is utf8 encoded:

> ABCDEF, ｋａｔａｋａｎａ, カタカナ and �K�{�`�F�b�N�G���[

One idea that I've been trying is to get the bytes of the string using utf-8 encoding then also get the bytes of the string using the default encoding then compare like so:

```
byte[] utf8byte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
if(utf8byte.length == bytes.length) {
   return true;
}
```

However given this logic, only the first string would return true. From my understanding, this is because not all characters use only 1 byte.

So what is the best approach you can suggest to check whether a string from the database is utf-8 encoded or not? I'd really appreciate any idea. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: My understanding, and I'm prepared to be shot down by @JonSkeet, is that in general you _can't_ determine the encoding simply by looking at the data in the byte stream.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The Java database driver reads the encoded byte string from the database and converts it to a Java string. The Database may choose to send the string as UTF-8, UTF-16 or any other encoding the driver understands.

Once it's a Java string it no longer contains any traces of the original encoding. `getBytes()` will use your system character encoding to decode the string. It has no relevance to the Database encoding.

Yes, Java uses UTF-16 under the hood but it's irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure, I understand fully so... how about if I check the encoding of the column value directly on the database? I'm using oracle db. Would that be possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need to check the encoding

Comment: Not to divulge on too many details, we're transferring our current data to a new system and database. What I'm doing is simply a "checker" to ensure that all our data are transferred correctly, including ensuring that the data are correctly encoded to utf-8. (many of the data would be in kanji and kana characters).

Comment: Assuming you've created your tables or columns with UTF-8 encoding, then all you need to do is to do a straight String compare of each row of data from the two databases.

Comment: In this case, a string comparison of the old version and the new version is sufficient, if they did not convert correctly, they would not be legible to Java.