# Repalce UTF8mb4 charactres with '?' in java

Tags: java, regex

Currently my database doesn't support utf8mb4 characters. I have to replace those characters with "?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC url for MySQL configuration to use utf8 character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058297/jdbc-url-for-mysql-configuration-to-use-utf8-character-encoding)

Comment: See [Detecting a utf8mb4 charset requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465439/detecting-a-utf8mb4-charset-requirement)

Comment: I  need regex to replace those characters in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String in="your input string";    
in.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFF]", "?")
```